# C++ refuses to recognize strings

Tags: c++, string

I have this structure:

```
struct FileData
{
    string fileName;
    int filePath;
    string fileSize;
    string fileHash;
    public:
    FileData (string name, int path, string size, string hash) :
    fileName(name), filePath(path),fileSize(size),fileHash(hash) {}
};
```

When I try to initialize it like this :

```
string name = dir[i].substr(delimiter+1);
string path = dir[i].substr(0, delimiter);
int size = FileSizeInBytes(dir[i]);
string hash = "";
FileData *sample = new FileData (name,path,size,hash);
```

The following error message pops up :   No instance of constructor "FileData::FileData" matches the argument list; Argument types are: (std::string, std::string, int, std::string)

Remarks: I have included the string header (for some reason the word string, surrounded by <> does not appear in the question) and I have "using namespace std;" on the top of the code.I tried removing it and manually adding std:: before every string, still didn't work. Also the values I am trying to assign to the variables before creating the structure object are completely valid strings. I also tried writing

```
string name = "something";
```

but it still didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
FileData (string name, int path, string size, string hash)
```

notice the `int path`, should be `std::string path`

If this was be design though, you cant pass a `std::string` for the `path` argument, like you do at the moment

Comment: Thank you good sir, I think this is enough coding for today, I retire in embarassment